# Visual Studio 2022 docker debugging - "no symbols have been loaded"

Tags: docker, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug two C# .NET 6.0 Docker containers from Visual Studio 2022, but the breakpoints I set always show "*no symbols have been loaded*".

The two Docker containers are in a `docker-compose.yml` file, at version 3.9 and Docker Desktop shows them running okay.

In VS2022, I've tried `Debug` > `Attach to Process` with:

- `Connection Type` of "Docker (Linux Container)"
- `Debug these Code types` set to "Managed (.NET Core for Unix)".

I can list the contents of the containers and see the `.pdb` files.

I've tried deleting the containers and images in Docker Desktop, cleaning the VS solution and re-building and re-starting the containers, but get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're building the containers with the debug version of the code? Also, try clearing out **all** of your breakpoints from the solution, and running a Clean Solution and then retry. This sometimes helps.

Comment: Good points @akseli, but yes we're building debug version of code.   Just tried clearing out breakpoints, cleaning solution, rebuilding and resetting the breakpoints and still get error.    Are you able to debug containers in VS2022?

Comment: I haven't had to in past few months, but before that I remember everything working as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this ourselves by ensure the debug config was shown as in the steps and screenshot below.

## Simple scenario

- ensure `Debug` solution configuration is selected
- ensure the `Startup Project` is the `docker-compose` file
- ensure `Docker Compose` is shown and then click it to start debugging

[image]

With this config, all our breakpoints worked as expected and we don’t need to Attach to Process any more.

We can still see our various containers and their logs in both Docker Desktop and in the VS Containers window.

## Launch Profiles scenario

Additionally, we have it working on another solution that has Docker Compose Launch Profiles.

- Ensure the `docker-compose` file has profiles specified for the various services
- in the toolbar > Docker Compose > Manage Docker Compose Launch Settings, select the Docker Compose profile

[image]

- Under each service, ensure the one you want to debug is `Start debugging`
- Save
- Start debugging as in the simple scenario above

Answer (score 2):

You are probably experiencing an issue with the [Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022#BKMK__NET_Framework_Just_My_Code) feature.
The two easiest ways to get your symbols to load in this case are:
Uncheck "Enable Just My Code" in the debugger options:
[image: Enable Just My Code Option]
Or, open the Modules window, select your dll, right click and select "Load Symbols":
[image: Load Symbols]

Comment: This solution did work for us Nathan, but debugging using the docker-compose startup profile was more straightforward, and we don't need to Attach to Process any more, so we're using that approach now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to debug a referenced project make sure that `DebugType` option is set to `portable` to create cross-platform PDB file in the referenced project file. Learn more about `DebugType` in [C# Compiler Options that control code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/code-generation#debugtype).

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DebugType>Portable</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```